# Renumber ordering column in PostgreSQL 9.3

Tags: postgresql

I have an ordering column in a Postgres table, I'm trying to re-order that column in SQL on the fly. In MySQL I would just run this query:

```
SET @new_ordering = 1;
UPDATE grados SET g_order = (@new_ordering := @new_ordering + 1) ORDER BY g_order ASC;
```

But of course that isn't working in Postgres. How would I run something similar in Postgres updating the ordering column with new incrementing values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can easily be done using a window function in Postgres:

```
update grados
  set g_order = t.rn
from (
  select pk_column, 
         row_number() over (order by g_order) as rn
  from grados
) t
where t.pk_column = grados.pk_column;
```

You need to replace `pk_column` with your real primary key column to get a correct join.

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/14a67/1

Comment: The problem is that isn't letting me set the "starting" number and go from there. The other example had a starting number that I could set.

Comment: @jfreak53: a starting number is not a problem. Just use `g_order = t.rn + starting_number` or use `starting_number + row_number() ...` in the inner select